# how to insert user defined data type in mule 4

Tags: oracle, esb, mule4

these are my data types

```
 create type addressTypes as object (Street  VARCHAR2(50),
      City    VARCHAR2(25),
      State   VARCHAR2(25),
    Zip     VARCHAR2(25));

 create type person as object
 (Name     VARCHAR2(25),
Address  addressTypes);
```

this is my table 
create table cusdetail (
      cid  NUMBER,
      Person    person
  );

how to insert in mule 4 database connector

insert into cusdetail (cid,Person) values(:cid,:Person)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    cid:payload.cid,
    Person:"person" ++ "(" ++(payload.name) ++ "," ++ "addressTypes"
      ++ "(" ++ (payload.street)   ++ "," ++ 
(payload.city)  ++ "," ++  (payload.state) 
 ++ "," ++  (payload.zip) ++ ")" ++ ""

}
```

payload used

```
{
    "name":"namecheck",
    "city":"chennai",
    "zip":"123456",
    "street":"2stret",
    "state":"TN",
    "cid":"12"

 }
```

need to insert successfully in db

Comment: did you sorted each value for payload as default empty string before concating them, as you will get `null` error, can you please post your dataweave payload before insert statement

Comment: i have added the payload @ven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mule 4 calling stored procedure with userdefined data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57494941/mule-4-calling-stored-procedure-with-userdefined-data-type)